# Using the line...file directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is an example usage of why someone would want to reset/change the current line number or filename in a program using the `#line` directive, for example:

```
#line 10000 "somefile.c"
printf("File: %s, Line: %d", __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

What would be an example of how that could be useful?

Comment: "Someone": generally never.  It's intended to be used by scripts or programs that generate C code from other code -- that way, error messages can refer to the original code. (Also, once upon a time, the C preprocessor itself was a separate program, and it used the equivalent of `#line` to pass the original line numbers, before `#include` processing, through to the compiler proper.)

Comment: In autogenerated c-code, when transforming code from one sourcefile to another. When you have errors in the resulting file, you typically want to know which line in the original sourcefile created the error. It is typically generated by the c preprocessor.

Comment: For better or worse, one part of the project I work on had a source file that was created by `cat file1.c file2.c … file9.c > code.c`. Each of the component files had `#line 2 "file1.c"` or equivalent at the top so that compilation errors from the composite `code.c` attributed the error to the correct source file. I got to improve that by creating `code.c` as a normal checked in file containing `#include "file1.c"` `#include "file2.c"` … `#include "file9.c"`, so that the `#line` directives are no longer needed, though they do no harm either (beyond bumping the line numbers in the files by 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive is used by programs that generate C code automatically, as `flex(1)` or `yacc(1)`, to indicate where in the original source file was the code inserted.

Imagine that you make a grammar specification for `yacc(1)` in a file that at some point inserts into the source file it generates (`yy.tab.c`) the source code you provided to it to be substituted literally.  `Yacc` introduces references to it's source code, so you can go back to the original `.y` file and see the code you wrote

If you look at the C source file created by `yacc`, you will find directives like

```
#line 357 "myfile.y"
... /* your inserted code */
#line 20547 "yy.tab.c"
... /* more yacc generated code */
#line 380 "myfile.y"
... /* more literal code written by you */
#line 21250 "yy.tab.c"
...
```

so the debugger will insert the proper references to the real source file, and not to the `yacc` processed intermediate C source.

The `cpp` preprocessor indicates each change of file, by inserting a `#line 1 "stdio.h"` at the beginning of an `#include <stdio.h>` expansion, and a `#line 37 "my_original_source.c"` on returning back from the `#include` to include in the debugger info the proper lines in the source code.  You can see this happening if you just preprocess a source code:

```
cpp mysourcefile.c | more
```

and you will see a pair of `#line` directives on include entry and include exit points, reseting the line counter.

Comment: fantastic answer. Thank you very much. By the way, what are all the lines at the beginning for, such as: `# 1 "m.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4`

Comment: one more thing. Is `#357 "myfile.y"` shorthand for `#line 357 "myfile.y"`?